Using SwiftUI Picker control to select data from a @Query result
When entering data for a medication in my Health app I want the user to select the doctor prescribing the medication!  I have a table of doctors that I can @Query to build an array.  How do I allow the user to select the appropriate doctor using a SwiftUI Picker control.
The @Query is:
    @Query(sort: \MedicalPersonnel.surname) var medicalPersonnel: [MedicalPersonnel]

The picker control is:
                    Picker("Prescribed By", selection: $prescribedBy) {
                        ForEach(medicalPersonnel) { mp in
                            Text("\(mp.surname)").tag(mp)
                        }
                    }

I varied the .tag component without success!

How is prescribedBy declared? Maybe your issue is similar to this question

PrescribedBy is a defined in the table model as:  var PrescribedBy: String = ""

I don't know what you mean by table model but it needs to be the same type as the tag. See the answer I linked to.

To clarify, the variable you use for the selection: argument in the Picker needs to be the same type as the tag
